# Get the type for DIGlobalVariable - LLVM

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

How to find out type for the global variables. For example:

### C code

```c
int bar;  // global variable -> int type
int *ptr; // global variable -> int type

void foo() {} // some function
```

### LLVM IR

```
!0 = !DIGlobalVariableExpression(var: !1, expr: !DIExpression())
!1 = distinct !DIGlobalVariable(name: "bar", scope: !2, file: !8, line: 1, type: !10, isLocal: false, isDefinition: true)
!2 = distinct !DICompileUnit(language: DW_LANG_C_plus_plus_14, file: !3, producer: "clang version 13.0.0", isOptimized: false, runtimeVersion: 0, emissionKind: FullDebug, enums: !4, globals: !5, splitDebugInlining: false, nameTableKind: None)

!3 = !DIFile(filename: "example.cpp", directory: "/sample/")
!4 = !{}
!6 = !DIGlobalVariableExpression(var: !7, expr: !DIExpression())
!7 = distinct !DIGlobalVariable(name: "ptr", scope: !2, file: !8, line: 2, type: !9, isLocal: false, isDefinition: true)
!8 = !DIFile(filename: "./example.cpp", directory: "/sample/")
!9 = !DIDerivedType(tag: DW_TAG_pointer_type, baseType: !10, size: 64)
!10 = !DIBasicType(name: "int", size: 32, encoding: DW_ATE_signed)
```

Comment: GlobalVariable inherits GlobalObject and the line number is metadata, so [getMetadata()](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1GlobalObject.html#a8c4c0580bdb7ccc8210222c7b22522b7) is what you need. I don't seem to have the appropriate arguments to hand, I'm afraid.

Comment: Could you please tell how to get the type of the global variable. For Example: ptr (!7) has a type !9 which is based on baseType: !10 which is int. How to get this programmatically.

Comment: I'm sure you could find it based on the metadata, but why not just get the type from the GlobalVariable object? ->getInitializer()->getType(), for example.

Comment: It does not work as i have DIGlobalVariable object.
error: no member named 'getInitializer' in 'llvm::DIGlobalVariable'

Comment: The GlobalVariable does exist; normally one gets the DIGlobalVariable by starting from the GlobalVariable and all the DI… objects are optional. (The name DI… means "debug info for global varialbe".)

Comment: @arnt Thanks for the information. However, I'm getting the error:
llvm::DIGlobalVariable ->getInitializer()->getType()
error: no member named 'getInitializer'